# Is asking about replacement/change of Micro-USB to USB-C on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

So I have asked where to ask this, both on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367179/where-to-ask-about-hardware-development) and [SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14496/asking-about-replacement-change-of-micro-usb-and-usb-c-on-topic), and at this point no one sounds too convinced, so I thought I'd ask here first to see if it was on-topic.

I have a small Bluetooth reciever that uses a Micro-USB to charge with. However, the port is having some connectivity issues, so I was interested in asking about the viability of "upgrading" to a "hardier" port, like USB-C.

The question is:

- Can it be done?
- If so, how? (I realize that at first glance, the pin/connection configs are different for both ports).

Is EE.SE the place to ask this?

Comment: I feel that that's a valid SE.EE design question. However, that's a demanding task for an existing product - I suspect you may well find it easier to address whatever the connectivity issues are using micro-usb. | You can buy USBC-micro adapters/converters. I do not know what level of functionality is achievable.  Some are so low cost that they are likely to be a basic physical connection with perhaps resistors to operate USBC in its basic 5V mode. Others are costly enough that you'd hope they do something useful :-).

Comment: "the port is having some connectivity issues"  What does that even mean? If it's just used for charging and that doesn't work reliably, then maybe the connector is just broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check a site to see if a question is ok to ask, visit their help center. Our list of topics is here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart
> phones, except when designing these products or modifying their
> electronics for other uses

EE.SE is a place to ask questions if you have a design question. Which usually means having a schematic or block diagram.